# Можно ли в C++ передавать в конструктор предка указатель на другого уже сконструированного предка?

Tags: c++, наследование, конструктор

Я не могу найти ответ на следующий вопрос.

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
class A
{
    // ...
}

class B
{
    public:
    B(A* _a) : a{ _a } {}

    private:
    A *a;
};

class C : private A, public B
{
    public:
    C() : B{ this } {}
};
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, является ли этот код корректным?

Я предполагаю, что да. При передаче в конструктор `B` (`C::B`) указателя `this`, он (указатель) автоматически (статически) преобразуется к указателю на `A` (`C::A`). А поскольку подобъект `A` (`C::A`) уже сконструирован, проблем возникнуть не должно.

PS. Описанный выше код был придуман, чтобы решить следующую проблему:

```
class C : public B
{
    public:
    C() : B{ &a } {}// UB

    private:
    A a;
};
```

Судя по всему, такой код имеет неопределенное поведение из-за того, что в конструктор `C::B()` передается адрес объекта, который еще не существует. Да, память под него уже выделена (хотя, это может зависеть от реализации), но объекта еще нет.

Таким образом, иногда при компиляции получается неработающий код.

Comment: я не по теме, но какую цель вы этим преследуете?

Comment: @есть старый код, в котором было обнаружено неопределенное поведение. Единственный быстрый способ его убрать, не переписывая всю кодовую базу, - это сделать, как в примере из вопроса.

Comment: Код корректен. Что вызвало сомнение? Есть потенциальная опасность, что пользователь переставит базовые классы... (это не будет диагоностированно компилятором).

Comment: @Chorkov, понял, спасибо.

Comment: Указатели можно создавать даже на несконструированные классы, так что даже если поменять местами `A` и `B`, все будет нормально.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, дополнил вопрос для более подробного раскрытия ситуации.

Comment: В [`[basic.life]/6`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6) написано, что так делать можно, насколько я понимаю.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, там имеется множество оговорок. Вероятно, наш случай попадает под эти оговорки.

Comment: @MGNeo Возможно ваш настоящий код и попадает, но код в вопросе не попадает.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я думаю, что эта проблема возникла у нас из-за того, что `A` и `B` являются наследниками стандартных потоковых классов. Проблема воспроизводится с одним компилятором, но не воспроизводится с другим. Видимо, в некотором окружении мы нарушаем правила, которые позволяют использовать адрес объекта, хранилище для которого уже выделено, но пока никак не инициализировано.